# script to combine values to another line

Tags: batch-file, awk, sed, grep, cut

I have a file that outputs a script syntax on one like and a value on another if it exist. I'd like to put the second line on the first to get something like this.

1) Move the below line to the script line above

2) If two or more items exist, duplicate the script.bat line

FROM:

```
script.bat -sdwmp 113311715863711636053
script.bat -sdwmp 105122741610948533232
;3d7aabfcb599c7ca;1;1439
script.bat -sdwmp 114919591391016539593
;3f313f55f7b18901;1;1439
script.bat -sdwmp 107509497927259675129
;32e12ca50705058e;1;1439
;3bcc63088792d44f;1;1439
script.bat -sdwmp 103610502293436364050
;3e868ba2e46448e9;1;1439
script.bat -sdwmp 111204415260699995229
;39010632a8ffb1e3;1;1439
```

TO:

```
script.bat -sdwmp 113311715863711636053
script.bat -sdwmp 105122741610948533232;3d7aabfcb599c7ca;1;1439
script.bat -sdwmp 114919591391016539593;3f313f55f7b18901;1;1439
script.bat -sdwmp 107509497927259675129;32e12ca50705058e;1;1439
script.bat -sdwmp 107509497927259675129;3bcc63088792d44f;1;1439
script.bat -sdwmp 103610502293436364050;3e868ba2e46448e9;1;1439
script.bat -sdwmp 111204415260699995229;39010632a8ffb1e3;1;1439
```

Comment: Based on your previous batch file questions, I can see you know how to at least read a file with a batch file. So I am pretty sure you can at least make an attempt at coding this and then ask for help with the code you are trying to use.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following(tested on your sample shown data only).

```
awk '/^script\.bat/{if(!flag && val){print val};val=$0;next} /^;/{flag=1;print val $0}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
/^script\.bat/{
  if(!flag && val){
    print val
  }
  val=$0
  next
}
/^;/{
  flag=1
  print val $0
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too here.

```
awk '
/^script\.bat/{       ##Checking condition if a line starts from script.bat then do following.
  if(!flag && val){   ##Checking condition if variable flag is NOT set and variable val is SET then do following.
    print val         ##Printing variable val value here.
  }
  val=$0              ##Setting variable val value to current line here.
  next                ##next will skip all further statements from here onwards.
}
/^;/{                 ##Checking condition here if a line starts from semi colon then do following.
  flag=1              ##Making variable flag value to 1 here.
  print val $0        ##Printing value of variable val and current line here.
}' Input_file         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: `;` is not special, no need to escape.

Comment: @karakfa, thank you sir, I have updated it now.

Answer (score 1):

A Batch-file solution, for the collection... **`;)`**

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "delims= eol=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line2=%%a"
   if "!line2:~0,1!" equ ";" (
      echo !line1!!line2!
      set "first="
   ) else (
      if defined first echo !line1!
      set "line1=%%a"
      set "first=1"
   )
)
if defined first echo !line1!
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick version would be:

```
/^script\.bat/{if(!c) print f; f=$0;c=0;next}
{print f $0;c++}
END{if(!c) print f}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is under windows I'd use PowerShell (v3+) as a tool.
Reading and saving `.\sample.txt`

```
powershell -Nop -C  "(gc .\sample.txt)|%{$i=0}{if($_[0] -ne ';'){if(!$i){$_;$i++};$L=$_} else{$L+$_}}|Set-Content .\sample.txt"
```

Got a bit cryptic with a one line PowerShell script wrapped in batch.

Comment: This not works. The two "semicolon" lines below `script.bat -sdwmp 107509497927259675129` are joined to the same line, not to separate lines...

Comment: @Aacini thanks for the hint, overlooked that. Changed with a flag and delayed output.